# Customer Community Sharing

Tags: community, sharing, sharing-sets

We have a customer community set up, and we are sharing custom objects based on a lookup to account. We created a sharing set - selected the correct profile and then we added sharing based on user.account = customObject__c.Account__c

Now on the same custom object we have an other lookup to account to specify a third party and we want to give users which belong to that account also access to that same record.

But it seems that this is not possible without creating a new profile, which of course we want to avoid as much as possible. Otherwise a user who have access to his own records and records linked to the other lookup would need to switch profiles before viewing the other records.

Is there a way we can handle this in a more elegant way? One profile with a sharing set that looks at 2 lookups.

Comment: i ran into a similar requirement, and it was not possible to add two sharing set rules on a single object, no matter how many look ups there are.  if your community users' licenses are ```customer community plus``` they at least are part of the standard sharing system and can have manual/apex sharing used to expose the records. https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=users_license_types_communities.htm&language=en_US

Comment: @Andrew, If you would, please re-post your comment as an answer since it appears to answer the question. Thanks!

Comment: @crmprogdev done and done!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i ran into a similar requirement, and it was not possible to add two sharing set rules on a single object, no matter how many look ups there are. if your community users' licenses are customer `community plus` they at least are part of the standard sharing system and can have manual/apex sharing used to expose the records.  https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=users_license_types_communities.htm&language=en_US