# Customer Community Sharing (any update)

Tags: community, sharing-rule, sharing-sets

We have a customer community set up, and we are sharing custom objects based on a lookup to account. We created a sharing set - selected the correct profile and then we added sharing based on user.account = customObject__c.Account__c

Now on the same custom object we have an other lookup to account to specify a third party and we want to give users which belong to that account also access to that same record.

But it seems that this is not possible without creating a new profile, which of course we want to avoid as much as possible. Otherwise a user who have access to his own records and records linked to the other lookup would need to switch profiles before viewing the other records.

This question was asked here four years ago. Is there a way we can handle this
now.One profile with a sharing set that looks at 2 lookups.

Comment: Please link to the question that was asked four years ago rather than just referencing it.

Comment: This seems to be the relevant link https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/46756/customer-community-sharing?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

There is still no way to do this with a Customer Community profile due to the limitations of Sharing Sets. It would be necessary to add a different profile to the Community for the users needing access to the other accounts and create a separate sharing set for them using the other lookup field to Account.

It is a scenario where the Customer Community Plus licence is more effective as it would allow a trigger to put in Apex Sharing or a criteria based sharing rule to be used.